# How to use other QUEUE_DRIVER than default in laravel 5.1 queue?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-queue

I my apps in queue.php I have set:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'rabbitmq'),
```

this is proper for most jobs in app, but i would like to use also 'database' driver and add jobs to postgresql db.

It works of course if I change default setting to:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

But then rabbitmq doesn't work.

I don't know how to use other 'QUEUE_DRIVER' than default?

I would like to use both for different jobs.

It doesn't works:

```
php artisan queue:listen database
```

because there is nothing there.

I will be glad for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/master/README.md

```
use Illuminate\Queue\Capsule\Manager as Queue;

$queue = new Queue;

$queue->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'queue' => 'default',
]);

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$queue->setAsGlobal();
```

In this way you should be able to create another queue object than the default one (name it `$rabbitQueue` for example), using a custom connection / driver. All subsequent calls to `$rabbitQueue->push()` to this instance will push messages to RabbitMQ. Other `$queue->push()` still using default connection.

Comment: Thanks, it helps.
I did simply: 
   Queue::connection('database')->push($job);